# I am putting a 800sf mobile behind my shop can i run my 100amp 3-3-3-5 supply line through my rafters to the disconnect to the back of my shop for it

Tags: wiring

I have a sub panel in the front of my shop. I'm putting a 800sf ADU in for my motherinlaw behind my shop. I need a disconnect on my shop to the mobile because it is over 35' away from my shop.  I have been told I would only need a 50 amp supply to it so I'm going with a 100amp line just so there won't be any issues if we add to it.  My question is: "is it going to be up to code to run my 3-3-3-5 supply line up my wall from my panel and run it down my 2x6 (battens or pullin) to the back of the shop then down to the disconnect?"

Comment: Why are you using copper for this? 1-1-1-3 Al SER is far cheaper, and no, it won't raise your insurance rates either

Answer (score 2):

You can run SER cable in the same manner as type NM (Romex). The same rules for fastening and supporting apply. You can also run it outdoors and exposed to sunlight. It cannot be used below grade either by direct burial or in conduit. It must not be installed in locations where subject to physical damage, so typically below 8ft, with the exception of where it drops down into the panel.

Also, I agree with the commenter that you should run #1 SER AL or even #2 on a 90 amp breaker as #2 is more readily available.

Comment: Just thought of this, but since an ADU is a "dwelling unit", #2 Al SER would be legal at 100A here

Comment: That's a good point. When we put meter banks in, the wires from the meter breakers are feeders and we do 100amps on 2-2-2-4. I'm wondering though if this applies to a feeder from another dwelling unit though. It would be an interesting conversation with an inspector 

Comment: Yeah, most folks who write ADU ordinances aren't concerned about their impact on the electrical code (210.25 comes to mind, but this is also a good point :)

Comment: Good point. 210.25 applies to common area branch circuits. I don't think an ADU qualifies in that respect as it's more like a guest house. One could argue that the ADU tenant needs access to the breaker feeding their panel, but the home owner could argue that the property is under 24/7 management/maintenance.